# Getting org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find object with id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two equivalent methods that are returning a list of  `Traning` objects for the particular trainer between two dates.

Queries look like:

```
  @Query(
      value =
          "SELECT t FROM Training t INNER JOIN t.trainingParticipants p "
              + "WHERE p.trainer = :trainer_id "
              + "AND t.trainingDate.startDate <= :trainingStartDate "
              + "AND t.trainingDate.endDate <= :trainingEndDate")
  List<Training> findTrainingOfTrainer(
      @Param("trainer_id") Long trainerId,
      @Param("trainingStartDate") LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      @Param("trainingEndDate") LocalDateTime trainingEndDate);

  // and equivalent version
  List<Training> findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingDate_StartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingDate_EndDateGreaterThanEqual(
      Long trainerId,
      LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      LocalDateTime trainingEndDate);

  default List<Training> trainerTrainingsBetweenPeriod(
      Long trainerId,
      LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      LocalDateTime trainingEndDate) {
    return findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingDate_StartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingDate_EndDateGreaterThanEqual(
        trainerId, trainingStartDate, trainingEndDate);
  }
```

My training class looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
public class Training extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "training", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "difficulty_level")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DifficultyLevel difficultyLevel;

  @Column(name = "completed")
  boolean completed;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "training_participants_id", unique = true)
  private TrainingParticipants trainingParticipants;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "training_data_id", unique = true)
  private TrainingDate trainingDate;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
}
```

TrainingParticipants looks like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TrainingParticipants {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id", unique = true)
  private User trainer;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = TrainingParticipants.class)
  private Set<User> trainee;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "trainingParticipants")
  private Training training;
}
```

TrainingDate class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
class TrainingDate {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private LocalDateTime startDate;

  private LocalDateTime endDate;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "trainingDate")
  private Training training;
}
```

User class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id")
  private Account account;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private UserType userType;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Training> training;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "trainer")
  private TrainingParticipants trainingParticipants;

  public User() {}

  public User(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
  }

  public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
  }

  public Set<Training> getTrainingParticipants() {
    return training;
  }
}
```

I prepared tests with H2 in-memory database to check if my two methods bring the desired effect and it looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TrainingServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private TrainingRepository repository;

  @Test
  void shouldReturnTrainerTrainingBetweenTwoDates() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    repository.saveAll(trainingDataStub());
    List<Training> trainingOfTrainer = repository
        .findTrainingOfTrainer(1L, now.minusDays(7), now.plusDays(7));

    assertNotNull(repository.findTrainingOfTrainer(1L, now.minusDays(7), now.plusDays(7)));
    assertEquals(2, trainingOfTrainer.size());
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnTrainerTrainingBetweenTwoDatesSpringData() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    repository.saveAll(trainingDataStub());
    List<Training> trainingOfTrainer = repository
        .trainerTrainingsBetweenPeriod(1L, now.minusDays(7), now.plusDays(7));

    assertNotNull(repository.findTrainingOfTrainer(1L, now.minusDays(7), now.plusDays(7)));
    assertEquals(2, trainingOfTrainer.size());
  }


List<Training> trainingDataStub() {
    return
        List
            .of(
                Training.builder()
                    .id(1L)
                    .trainingParticipants(
                        TrainingParticipants.builder().id(2L).trainer(User.builder().id(1L).build())
                            .build())
                    .trainingDate(
                        TrainingDate.builder()
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2)).build()).build(),
                Training.builder()
                    .id(1L)
                    .trainingParticipants(
                        TrainingParticipants.builder().id(2L).trainer(User.builder().id(1L).build())
                            .build())
                    .trainingDate(
                        TrainingDate.builder()
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(4))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3)).build()).build(),
                Training.builder()
                    .id(1L)
                    .trainingParticipants(
                        TrainingParticipants.builder().id(2L).trainer(User.builder().id(1L).build())
                            .build())
                    .trainingDate(
                        TrainingDate.builder()
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(10))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(9)).build()).build());
  }

}
```

When I am starting my tests I am receiving an error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.application.training.TrainingParticipants with id 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.application.training.TrainingParticipants with id 2
```

Generally speaking, I want to have a relation like:
-User has a collection of training
-Training has single object TrainingDate and Training Participants where one is a trainer and there can be a trainee collection.

I will be grateful for suggestions on if my current mapping coincide with the above assumptions and how to solve a problem with missing id for test purposes.